# Ruby on Rails: Where is jquery-rails located?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

In Gemfile i got gem 'jquery-rails', if i commented it the following line doesn't work. I get routing error.

```
<%= link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete) %>
```

But if i uncommented gem 'jquery-rails' the logout link works.

But i don't see any javascript file in app/assets named 'jquery-rails'. Where is this file located ?

How is this file called and how it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file is in the jquery-rails gem and will be referenced in your application.js manifest.

The actual jquery code will be in a folder in the gem source tree.

Rails 3.1 allows gem authors to make files available to the asset pipeline, and these are included in the Rails pipeline path at startup.

Comment: Why doesn't commenting gem 'jquery-rails' work for that logout link ? Why do i get routing error if i comment it ? What's the relation with that jquery-rails with the link_to 'logout' link ?

Comment: What is happening is that the link is changed by the javascript to send the logout request to the correct action (delete). Without the UJS code the link goes to the wrong place.